# Storing output of filter activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm creating a pipeline which filters the input from the source SQL table based on few columns (using Filter activity) and then copies it to an Azure SQL table. But the copy activity expects a SQL query input instead of an array. Clearly, I'm unable to save the output of a filter activity to a table or a file.

The error I'm facing is:

> Failed to convert the value in 'sqlReaderQuery' property to 'System.String' type.Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct.
>
> Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Object must implement IConvertible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter activity will not have the output as a table ( which you will need for the copy activity ). Since in your case the source is SQL , you can use the SQL query to filter the data in the query itself when you are configuring the source .